# Faster Way to work through std::map

Tags: matrix, stdmap

I got a problem. I got a programme running using a map like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix{
public:
    //--- Parameters ---
    std::map<std::array<int,2>,T> data;
    const int nRow;
    const int nCol;
```

this is working well with all methods and operators. 
Until now I am using for-loops for the operators like for example this:

```
Matrix& operator+=(const Matrix<T>& other){
for (auto r = 0; r<nRow;r++){
    for (auto c= 0; c<nCol;c++){
    if(other.data.count({r,c}))
            data[{r,c}] +=other[{r,c}];
};
};
return *this;
};

Matrix operator+(const Matrix<T>& other){
    return Matrix(*this)+=other;
};
```

Unfortunately if the matrices get really huge this method is superslow. Really slow. So I tried something like `std::transform` and so on. 
But unfortunately I can not get it to work within the map structure. Do you probably have an idea to either make it work or make it faster? It really takes ages and I am new to Cpp, so I want to learn how to do it the right way.

Thank you very much :)